# Number Field not showing number in React native sms linking

Tags: react-native

Instead of No Name i want a number to be shown like this

[image]

I am using expo-cli with iOS simulator

```
Linking.openURL('sms:+15105550101&body=Hi')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, the correct syntax for `Linking.openURL` should be:

```
Linking.openURL(`sms:${phone}&body=${body}`)
```

Try to change the `body`.

Comment: cant we directly pass the number and message?

Comment: @HamzaFayyaz the `body` should be the message body...

Comment: i just checked your syntax and the problem remains still. Maybe its cuz of simulator.